# Inserting at the tail of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm working with linked lists for my first time and have to create a function that can insert a node at the end of a doubly linked list. So far I have

```
void LinkedList::insertAtTail(const value_type& entry) {
    Node *newNode = new Node(entry, NULL, tail);
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    ++node_count;
}
```

The Node class accepts a value to be stored, a value for the next pointer to point to, and a value for the previous pointer in that order. Whenever I try to insert a node here, I get an error saying there was an unhandled exception and there was an access violation in writing to location 0x00000008.

I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong here but I assume it has something to do with dereferencing a null pointer based on the error message. I would really appreciate some help with solving this problem.

EDIT:

I should have clarified early, tail is a pointer that points to the last node in the list. Tail->next accesses the next variable of that last node which, before the function runs, points to NULL but after it executes should point to the new node created.

Comment: Show us: the `LinkedList` and `Node` classes, as there's not much context in your first post.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `tail` and `tail->next` pointing to the `newNode`? *(Looks like a circular reference, but I could be wrong.)*

Comment: Is your `tail` initially NULL? You can't dereference it in `tail->next` until it already points to the first element

Comment: The order of operations you have seem correct. The parameters your passing indicate proper node initialization. Just by this I would hazard a guess your tail pointer is broken or the copy-constructor of value_type is stomping on memory. Showz us more code plz. and think about `if (tail)` in front of that `tail->next` assignment. Likewise, where's the head-assignment on the chance this list is purely empty and the tail insert is the first one?? might want that as well.

Comment: @Thomas, when tail->next is set to point to the newNode, tail references the former tail.

Comment: @BrandonBosso  and don't forget, if the tail is NULL, chances are the head is as well. I.e. first node-insert at head OR tail should result in *both* referencing the node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where does `tail` point to initially? If it's NULL then you'll dereference a null pointer when trying to insert the first element.

Does it help if you test `tail` before dereferencing it?

```
void LinkedList::insertAtTail(const value_type& entry) {
    Node *newNode = new Node(entry, NULL, tail);
    if (tail)
        tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    ++node_count;
}
```

If `tail` is null and `offsetof(Node, next)` is 8 that would explain the access violation, because `tail->next` would be at the address 0x00000000 + 8 which is 0x00000008, so assigning to `tail->next` would try to write to memory at that address, which is exactly the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! It turned out that tail was pointing to NULL. After I realized that it was an easy fix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell what's causing the error without knowing the state of the list *before* the insertion operation (which is actually *append* rather than insert, by the way).

There's a good chance you're not handling the initial case of appending to an empty list. The basic algorithm is (an empty list is indicated by a NULL head pointer, everything else is indeterminate):

```
def append (entry):
    # Common stuff no matter the current list state.

    node = new Node()
    node->payload = entry
    node->next = NULL

    # Make first entry in empty list.

    if head = NULL:
        node->prev = NULL
        head = node
        tail = node
        return

    # Otherwise, we are appending to existing list.

    next->prev = tail
    tail->next = node
    tail = node
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your LinkedList has both a head AND tail, maybe try:

```
void LinkedList::insertAtTail(const value_type& entry) 
{
    Node *newNode = new Node(entry, NULL, tail);
    if (tail)
        tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    if (!head)
        head = newNode;
    ++node_count;
}
```

Just a shot in the dark